# Looking for way to perform stuff before "enter" on ng-animate, like beforeAddClass

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation

```js
//this top animation is what I have seen and was hoping to find a way to do with enter-leave below

app.animation('.answer-animation', function(){
  return {
    beforeAddClass: function(element, className, done){
      if (className == 'answer') {
         console.log('stuff todo beforeAddClass');
      }
      else {
        done();
      }
    },

    beforeRemoveClass: function(element, className, done) {
      if (className == 'answer') {
        console.log('stuff todo beforeRemoveClass');
      }
      else {
        done();
      }
    }
  };
  
  /*what I am trying to do below*/
  app.animation(".viewAnimation", function ($anchorScroll, $timeout) {
 return {
   //***********would like to do something before enter
     enter: function(element, done) {
    },
  leave: function(element, done) {
       }
  };
 });
```

> Hi, I am looking for a way to hook into the angular lifecycle, similar beforeAddClass that is available for ng-hide. For mine, I have a view animation that before entering, I would like to do something. There is no beforeEnter that I can find or anyway to do something before "enter" executes. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try The ng-[event]-prepare class from the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response @Kraken , but this only fires when the animation is initialized. For subsequent enter animations, it never fires again. I was hoping to find something that fires every time before the enter animation runs.